# Add space between textContent data scraped from website using PHP DOM

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing, domdocument

I am trying to add a comma and whitespace to some data I am scraping from a website. The data scrapes successfully, but they are muddled up together, and the space and comma are trying to add only get added to the last item. Here is the code I currently have

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);

$class_ops = 'ipc-inline-list ';
$class_opp = 'ipc-inline ';
$node = $finder->query("//div[@class='$class_ops']//ul[@class='$class_opp']");

foreach ($node as $index => $t) {
    if ($index == 3) {
        $la = $t->textContent.", ";
    }
}
```

echo $la;

**Current Result**

```
DoyleBrainDavid,
```

**Expected Result**

```
Doyle, Brain, David
```

Comment: what `if($index == 3)` is supposed to do?

Comment: @IłyaBursov the data am trying to scrape is in the index(3) inside an li class

Comment: @user3783243 yes it has only that content but they are inside a li class so the result are not technical written together there are three or more li class which contain the each od the response

Comment: @user3783243 var_dump($t->textContent) gives `string(15) "DoyleBrainDavid"`

Comment: @SerenityEmmanuel Oh, okay, misread previous comment. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code

```html
$c1 = curl_init('https://stackoverflow.com/');
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($c1);

if (curl_error($c1))
    die(curl_error($c1));
// Get the status code
$status = curl_getinfo($c1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c1);
preg_match_all('/<span(.*?)<\/span>/s', $html, $matches1);


foreach($matches1[0] as $k=>$v){
    $enc =  mb_detect_encoding($v);
    $v = mb_convert_encoding($v,$enc, "UTF-8");
    $match1[$k] = strip_tags ($v);
    //$match1[$k] = preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', '', $match1[$k]);
}

var_dump($match1);
```

In your case you can replace like this

```html
preg_match_all('/<div class="ipc-inline-list">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $html, $matches1);
```

This return array with matches.

I hope this can be helpful for you

Comment: could u kindly explain ur answer so i can implement in my code accordingly, currently the output returns null after I replaced mine as this `preg_match_all('/<div class=$class_ops><ul class=$class_opp>(.*?)<\/div>/s', $html, $matches1);` Thanks alot

Comment: A parser is the correct approach, the regex will cause issues later.

Answer (score 0):

You want each `li`, not the `ul` as one block. Try:

```
$node = $finder->query("//div[@class='$class_ops']//ul[@class='$class_opp']/li");
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Mvfud

If that doesn't work the actual HTML content should be added to the question.

Comment: hi thanks this seems to work but am only able to get the first item how can i loop the li to get all the list not just the first li

Comment: @SerenityEmmanuel Please provide a real MVCE, and additional example can be added. As is I'd expect you to only get the last element. `$la =` should be `$la .=`. and you should define that outside the loop, or use an array and then implode it.